# Animating on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I've been trying to implement this myself as I wanted to understand how this works.

What I'm trying to do is very well displayed on https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/.

Simply put, the animations only trigger when scrolling down. Which is what I want to achieve.

So far, the idea I had was

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
   // if window.pageYOffset > the element's YOffset, trigger animation
   // If window.pageYOffset < make element default state again
})
```

I think this is the right idea. But it also has to be consistent across tablets and mobile which I believe the library I posted does.

Does anyone know how to achieve this very simply? I am sure it can be done very easily but cannot seem to get close to a solution.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. You can use `classList.add` in your if statement to add an animation class. Then update your question if that does’t produce the desired behaviour

Comment: @Kokodoko Yes but how do you get the element's position?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following amended code:

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#id_home").hide();
  var offset_top = 100; // Where you want the fade to begin 
  var check_div = function(verify) {
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (!$("#id_home:animated").length || verify) {
      if (scroll_top > offset_top) {
        $("#id_home").fadeIn(1300, function() {
          if (!verify) check_div(true);
        });

      } else {
        $("#id_home").fadeOut(1300, function() {
          if (!verify) check_div(true);
        });

      }
    }
  }

  check_div(false);
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    check_div();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<body style="height:999px;">
  <div id="id_home" style="margin-top:0px;background:#aaa;">Hello, my young friend</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#id_home {
  position: fixed;
}
```

See it here: https://jsfiddle.net/billy_farroll/pjj584rx/1/

Hope this is better.

Comment: Doesn't reanimate when I scroll up and down again.

Comment: Element is always at the top.

Comment: That’s because I positioned it fixed for the example. The Jquery code is what you need for the effect, then style and position however you choose in CSS.

Comment: the code is not what I need for the effect. The offset_top is always at 100. The point of this is to get this value to where ever the element is. To use this, I need to change it to a different value if the position changes, instead of getting it from the element itself. Moreover, this won't work correctly on different viewports.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out on my own.
The idea was to use offset on the element and iterate this until the body to get it's position.